# How do I add a new column to the Documents library upload form?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have added a column to the documents library of my SharePoint site and it appears on the edit form but it does not appear on the upload form. How do I get my new column to appear on the upload form?

Answer (score 0):

It should appear once the document has been uploaded. It will not appear on the upload form itself.